# How to find out, which program is using 24 GB RAM?

Tags: ubuntu, ram, htop

I've recently rented a new server with 50 GB RAM. And even though I haven't install any powerful soft on it, `htop` show that there are about one-half memory in usage (screenshot in attachment).

Could you explain why?

Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`free -h`

You will probably see, that Linux takes unused memory for caching and buffering.